# How to restart chrome browser without getting it crashed

Tags: winapi, nsis

I'm killing the process in order to close chrome.exe but when I re-open, it says that chrome has crashed.

I also tried:

```
FindWindow $0 "Chrome_WidgetWin_0"
${If} $0 <> 0 
    SendMessage $0 0x0112 0xF060 0
${EndIf}
```

But it doesn't seems to work

The code is NSIS but it uses WIN32 calls (findwindow, sendmessage).

Thanks

Comment: Of course it says that Chrome has crashed: **you crashed it**. Killing the process is not a standard way of closing an application.

Comment: Have you tried sending `WM_CLOSE` (0x0010) instead of `WM_SYSCOMMAND` (0x0112)?

Comment: Also remember that you can have multiple Chrome tabs and windows open; using `WM_CLOSE` is not going to be sufficient to get them all closed. Why are you trying to kill processes on the user's computer programmatically anyway?

Comment: @Chris - I have tried to use WM_CLOSE as well, and it doesn't seems to close chrome, maybe I'm not sending it to the correct window, I used Spy++ to get "Chrome_WidgetWin_0" class.

Comment: @CodyGray - I'm writing an nsis installer that installs a chrome extension and I have to restart chrome, if the user has it open.

Comment: It should close Chrome normally if you put a loop around it (while FindWindow returns a value <> 0 send the message). Like CodyGray wrote the user might have several windows and tabs open, which makes the loop necessary.

Comment: Seems like it would be worth the effort to figure out what the documented way of installing a Chrome extension is. Surely you're not the first person to do this. I have a couple of extensions installed in my Chrome browser. I suspect none of them killed the process or used any other hacks. I don't know personally, I've never written a Chrome extension. But Google does document these things.

Comment: Sending WM_CLOSE (0x0010) to all windows (there are several!) of "Chrome_WidgetWin_0" class works fine for me. Are you sure you're sending it to all  those windows?

Comment: @zenpoy You don't need to restart Chrome to install an extension!

Comment: Cody and Dan have the right message for you. Find out how to install the extension without committing murder along the way.

Comment: Actually since chrome 21 I do not know of a good way to "automatically" install an extension without restarting chrome (not using the store that is). Chrome have blocked easy-install of crx files from external sources and installing via .json has a [problem](http://crbug.com/41902) and I believe also requires a browser relaunch.

Comment: BTW: There is also an URL which **restarts chrome *without crash or loosing tabs*** : **`chrome://restart`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the correct window that can be closed with WM_SYSCOMMAND you can use:

```
FindWindow $0 "Chrome_WidgetWin_0" "" "" "Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND"
System::Call 'user32::GetParent(i r0)i.s'
pop $0

${If} $0 <> 0 
    SendMessage $0 0x0112 0xF060 0
${EndIf}
```

But as CodyGray commented, to install a Chrome extension you don't need to restart the browser at all. The documentation is located in [Google Chrome Documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/external_extensions.html)